# Iterate through snapshot 10 times

Tags: javascript

I tried to iterate this 10 times so it stops after 10.

Original, which works and runs:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    document.querySelector('#contents button[aria-label="Action menu"]').click();
    var things = document.evaluate('//span[contains(text(),"LIST2")]',document,null,XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,null);
        for (var i = 0; i < things.snapshotLength; i++) {
            things.snapshotItem(i).click();
        }       
}, 500)
```

Converted to `while` loop, this runs fine as well:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    document.querySelector('#contents button[aria-label="Action menu"]').click();
    var things = document.evaluate('//span[contains(text(),"LIST2")]',document,null,XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,null);
    let i = 0;
        while (i < things.snapshotLength) { 
            things.snapshotItem(i).click();
                i=i+1;
        }       
}, 500)
```

Then I tried to make it loop max 10 times, but all the ones have failed:

```js
setInterval(function() {
document.querySelector('#contents button[aria-label="Action menu"]').click();
var things = document.evaluate('//span[contains(text(),"LIST2")]',document,null,XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,null);
    let sum = 0;
        while (sum < 10 ){
                for (var i = 0; i < things.snapshotLength; i++) {
            things.snapshotItem(i).click();
                }   
            sum++;
        }
}, 500)
```

```js
setInterval(function() {
    document.querySelector('#contents button[aria-label="Action menu"]').click();
    var things = document.evaluate('//span[contains(text(),"LIST2")]',document,null,XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,null);
        let i = 0;
            while (i < 10) {
                things.snapshotItem(i).click();
                    i++;
        }       
}, 500)
```

I was told a `break` statement doesn't work with a `for` loop; I tried both and neither has worked:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    document.querySelector('#contents button[aria-label="Action menu"]').click();
    var things = document.evaluate('//span[contains(text(),"LIST2")]',document,null,XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,null);
    let i = 0;
    let sum = 0;
    while (sum < 10 ){
        while (i < things.snapshotLength) {
            if (things(i) < 4){
                break;}
                things.snapshotItem(i).click();
                sum += things.snapshotLength[i];
            }
                i=i+1;
                console.log(things(i));
        }       
}, 500)
```

Both don't work. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Your very first loop example should work fine. Your issue must be something about the calls to `snapshotLength` or `.snapshotItem()` or `document.evaluate`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand

Comment: Are you looking for `for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(10,things.snapshotLength); i++)`?

Comment: Though this does run. It does loop indefinitely not just 10 times.

Comment: Are you sure it's not running "indefinitely" because of the fact that you have wrapped it in setInterval which will, in effect, make a loop that runs forever?

Comment: You might be right. Do you know how to undo that.

Comment: What's the purpose of `setInterval()` in your code?

Comment: That's how I got it to run. But I only need to do that n number of times.

Comment: I removed the setInterval() but got error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'click')

Comment: You haven't shared your html, but it appears that `document.querySelector('#contents button[aria-label="Action menu"]')` doesn't exist. Is your script running before the DOM loads?

Comment: The first two work. They are fine its the loop I have an issue with.